# C# Reflection Expression Linq

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

I'm having some problems with C# dynamic generated lambda expressions.

Considering the following scenario:

```
public class Person {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Person> persons = new List<Person> () {
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Foo" },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Bar" },
    new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Baz" },
    new Person { Id = 4, Name = null },
};
```

Now, doing the follow code

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "arg");
Expression prop = Expression.Property(param, "Name");
Expression value = Expression.Constant("bar");
Type type = prop.Type;

MethodInfo toLower = typeof(String).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
Expression expLower = Expression.Call(prop, toLower);

Expression clausule = Expression.Call(expLower, type.GetMethod("Contains", new[] { type }), value);
Expression notNull = Expression.NotEqual(prop, Expression.Constant(null));

clausule = Expression.And(notNull, clausule);

var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(clausule, param);
```

The above code generate the following exp.

```
//arg => ((arg.Name != null) And (arg.Name.ToLower().Contains("bar")))
```

Now, trying to apply that to my list.

The filter below works

```
var filteredListThatWorks = persons.Where(arg => arg.Name != null && arg.Name.ToLower().Contains("bar")).ToList();
```

The one below throws exception of Null object ( because of Id 4 name)

```
var filteredListThatGivesExp = persons.Where(exp.Compile()).ToList();
```

The same expression, when generated by lambda, throws exp, when manually inputed, works.
Anyone knows a way to solve that ?

Br,

Comment: also keep in mind - when you use `var filteredListThatGivesExp = persons.Where(exp.Compile()).ToList();`, that is being compiled to a *delegate*, not an *expression tree*; if you want truly equivalent code, you should perhaps use `persons.AsQueryable().Where(...)`, which forces it to use the expression-tree API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`And` is `&`; you want to use `AndAlso` (`&&`):

```
clausule = Expression.AndAlso(notNull, clausule);
```

When in doubt, sharplab.io is an excellent tool here; if I use:

```
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> filter
        = arg => arg.Name != null && arg.Name.ToLower().Contains("bar");
```

it tells me that it compiles to be equivalent to:

```
// ...
BinaryExpression body = Expression.AndAlso(left, Expression.Call(instance, method, obj));
// ...
```

(note that it has to lie about some of the instructions though, as it compiles to things that can't actually be expressed in raw C#)

[see it in action](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsA6AGQEsA7ARzIFEAPABwTiiioHsaoChIigDMWAEwYAwhgDeRDIqxiUkgAqIofOQqV7RGADZ8A5hgCSAEzkYTcGLgxR7jgL669igzkwA5CGBwNnYOTi4Y7oR6kfoqACwYALIAFACUOlGeiizsnNx8ADwoAKwFGghaNAA0GMA8PIYAfI0YAGZUhvAIHllKALwYEAhmfS1DJmT+gRgAhAM0AK6GhhgAZKuDw5MBcGQAKjwUPADuiGlkUnwwELRQyQBEwEP3qYLRRK5AA==)

Comment: You deserve a cookie Sir! 

4 more mins to mark as Correct. Thank you very much